# Why is my file blob saving the whole webpage rather than the inputted string?

Tags: javascript, html, blob

I have this function taking in a string, and I want people to be able to download a text file consisting of that string. However, whenever I click the link, the downloaded file just consists of the entire HTML page instead of the string.

JS:

```
function downloadFile(names) {
  var text = names.toString();
  $('#downloadlink').href = createFile(text);
}

function createFile(text) {
  var data = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/plain'});

  if (textFile !== null) {
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile);
  }

  var textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);

  return textFile;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a download="colors.txt" href="" id="downloadlink">Download</a>
```

Why is it doing this?  Am I constructing the Blob incorrectly?  How do I fix it?

Comment: What's the difference between `createLessFile` and `createFile`? Where is `textFile` defined? What is being passed into `names` in `downloadFile`?

Comment: @BaileyParker sorry about that, it was a typo. `textFile` is defined there in `createFile`. `names` is a string array!

Comment: If I had to take a guess, `textFile` isn't actually defined then (it needs a var to be defined, otherwise it will be `undefined`) so when create file is called you try `window.URL.revokeObjectURL(undefined);` which probably errors and then the rest of the function doesn't complete.

Comment: `window.URL.revokeObjectURL` and `window.URL.createObjectURL` are totally new for me, +1

Comment: @BaileyParker good catch. It happens when I define it outside of the function, too, but definitely something I should fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that jQuery magic is obscuring what you're actually doing when you use `$('#downloadlink')`. jQuery wraps returns from `$` in a jQuery object which is an array like structure. So even though an id selector (possibly) returns one element, jQuery still hands you an array.

Because of this, you can't do `$('#stuff').href`. You instead need to use jQuery's [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) like this:

```
$('downloadLink').attr('href', createFile(text));
```

As with most jQuery functions, it applies some action to all of the elements in the array returned by `$`.

Working [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/liqaqiwero/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 1):

At runtime the href attribute is empty.
Add a $(document).ready function or use the classic way:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function()
{
    document.getElementById('downloadlink').href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(["content"], {type: 'text/plain'}));
});
```